# Receive игнорирует сообщения с data[0]

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp

Задача интегрироваться в систему где для связи между устройствами используется протокол tcp. Нужно разработать сервер, для другой логики работы с клиентами.  Подключение является постоянным.

При открытии сокета клиент отправляет пустое сообщение - оно успешно открывает соединение. Сервер может как отправить свою команду клиенту, так и ожидать сообщение от него. Общение между клиентом и сервером завершается отправкой сообщения с пустым содержимым клиентом или сервером. После завершения общения сервер посылает команду, или ждёт сообщения от клиента.

Что-бы отправить новую команду сервером, нужно завершить предыдущее общение. Но пустое сообщение от клиента, сервер игнорирует.

Я использовал [Асинхронное подключение с официального сайта](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example). При получении пустого сообщения сокет не заходит в `ReadCallback`. Я тестировал на синхронном сокете, там `Receive` так-же не слушает пустые сообщения. `Wireshark` эти запросы прекрасно видит

Может кто-нибудь подсказать как можно решить эту проблему? 
Возможно использовать другие средства?

Answer (score 0):

TCP сокеты не работают в терминах сообщений, по крайней мене не с точки зрения WinAPI и .NET. Сокет - это труба, в который вы пишете байты, которые читаются с другой стороны. Отправленное двумя "сообщениями" может дойти в виде одного вызова callback. И наоборот, отправленное одним сообщением может дойти на другую сторону двумя отдельными вызовами callback.

Пустое "сообщение", соответственно, не доходит никак - пока нет вычитываемых байт - callback не вызывается. [0 байт вычитается только в случае, если друга сторона закроет соединение.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync?view=netframework-4.8)

> For byte streams, zero bytes having been read indicates graceful closure and that no more bytes will ever be read.

Comment: Я так понимаю, как-то можно оборвать текущий поток данных `Shutdown`, и при этом не закрывать соединение. После пустого сообщения порт клиента не меняется, и общение может быть продолжено в нем.

Comment: @AlexandrPlas нет, нельзя.